# Howto implement a teleop node using rosjava?

Tags: turtlebot, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello..

i want to make new project.

the project is 'turtlebot teleoperation' using rosjava.

so i'm searching http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/javadoc/index-all.html
this page.

but i cannot find adjust API 'move, stop, turn etc...'

How can i make it? or Where can i get the example source?

please help me.

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40460/howto-implement-a-teleop-node-using-rosjava?/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, you should understand the basics of ROS, what nodes are, what topics are etc. Have a look at [these tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials). If you need C++ example code, have a look at the source code of [turtlebot_teleop](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/file/d82dd9c1c8a4/turtlebot_teleop).

The implementation is pretty simple: when you want to move the robot, publish a message of type geometry_msgs/Twist on the topic `cmd_vel`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-08-05**:
thankyou!
where can i get a sample code by rosjava?  not c++ code

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-05**:
Have a look at the android repository on rosjava.googlecode.com. Maybe you find something there. But be aware that rosjava is not released yet and its API is highly unstable and might change in the future. Not all apps in the android repository might still be working.